# Model Validation to allow only alphabet characters in textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, data-annotations

How can I annotate my model so I can allow only alphabets like A-Z in my text-box?

I know that I can use regex but can anyone show how to do that on text-box property itself using data annotation.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could annotate your model like this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
string TextBoxData {get; set;}
```

Then in your view you would use the helper

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TextBoxData)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TextBoxData )
```

Comment: How can we force to accept spaces in between. Ex: 'My Data Value' and Not 'My 4 Data5 Val4ue'

Answer (score 2):

You can use annotations for regular expression validation (if i understood your questions), something like that

```
        [RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z]",ErrorMessage="only alphabet")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write like this
 It matches First character must be an alpha word
 and following that matches any number of characters/hyphen/underscore/space

```
 [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+[ a-zA-Z-_]*$", ErrorMessage = "Use Characters only")]
```